# Haskell currying to remove argument variable at the end

Tags: haskell, function-composition, pointfree

I am a newbie trying to learn haskell, I tried to search for something similar in other forums but couldn't find a similar question.

```
addPoly :: (Num a)=>[[a]]->[a]
addPoly  x = map sum $ transpose x
```

runs fine

but when I remove x at the end it errors out

```
addPoly :: (Num a)=>[[a]]->[a]
addPoly  = map sum $ transpose
```

errors saying:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[[Integer]] -> [Integer]'
            with actual type `[Integer]'
In the expression: map sum $ transpose
In an equation for `addPoly': addPoly = map sum $ transpose

Couldn't match expected type `[[Integer]]'
            with actual type `[[a0]] -> [[a0]]'
In the second argument of `($)', namely `transpose'
In the expression: map sum $ transpose
In an equation for `addPoly': addPoly = map sum $ transpose
```

Couldn't figure out what I am missing here.

Disclaimer: this is not a homework problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$` is defined in Haskell as

```
f $ x = f x
infixr 0 $
```

So if you expand the first snippet of your code,

```
map sum $ transpose x
```

becomes

```
map sum (transpose x)
```

which will work.

But the second snippet

```
map sum $ transpose
```

becomes

```
map sum transpose
```

and when you call that with `x`, you get

```
map sum transpose x
```

which actually map's `sum` over `transpose` (and calls the result with argument `x`, which also doesn't make sense, and causes the error message you get, as `map` will return a `List`, not a function), and not over `transpose x`.

You need to use the `.` function for this, instead of `$`, which is defined as

```
(.) f g = \x -> f (g x)
```

If you do that, your code

```
map sum . transpose
```

becomes

```
\x -> map sum (transpose x)
```

and when you call this from on some parameter `x`, it simply becomes

```
map sum (transpose x)
```

which is the (correct) code we started with.

Let me know if something isn't clear.

Comment: I'll just add that the general rule of thumb when dropping arguments is to change your `$`s to `.`s.  Obviously this doesn't work in every case, but for the pattern `f x = g1 $ g2 $ g3 $ g4 x`, you can rewrite it as `f = g1 . g2 . g3 . g4`

Answer (score 1):

The proper code is:

```
addPoly :: (Num a)=>[[a]]->[a]
addPoly  = map sum . transpose
```

How to arrive at it? Remember the following two rules:

```
f $ x = f x
f. g $ x == (f.g) x == f (g x) == f $ g x
```

Thus,

```
addPoly  x = map sum $ transpose x
```

is rewritten as

```
addPoly  x = map sum $ transpose $ x
```

and then each `$` but the last are replaced by `.`.

```
addPoly  x = map sum . transpose $ x
```

Now, since you have only one `$` and the argument is only on the right of `$` you can switch to point-free style